# Copying Files into Arrays (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to read into a file, make it into an array and print it.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with this code. I've been trying to get a solution but all the solutions I can find are more advanced than what we should be using...I wrote a previous program using the same method but as a Double array. I can't seem to make it work for a String?

I keep getting [Ljava.lang.String;@3d4eac6 when I run it.

I just want it to print boysNames. boyNames.txt is just a list of 200 names in a text file.

Someone please help me, or let me know if this is possible?

this is my code so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {



    String[] boyNames = loadArray("boyNames.txt");
    System.out.println(boyNames);
}

public static String[] loadArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
    //create new array
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File (filename));
    int count = 0;
    //read from input file (open file)
    while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        inputFile.nextLine();
        count++;
    }
    //close the file
    inputFile.close();

    String[] array = new String[count];
    //reopen the file for input
    inputFile = new Scanner(new File (filename));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        array[i] = inputFile.nextLine();            
    }
    //close the file again
    inputFile.close();
    return array;
}
```

`

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;@3d4eac6` ... this looks like you are trying to print out an array.  Your code actually looks OK to me.  What is the error?

Comment: That is what's weird...It compiles for me, but when I run it, it just prints " [Ljava.lang.String;@3d4eac6 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java arrays don't override [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), so you get a generic `[Ljava.lang.String;@3d4eac6` (or similar) when you try to print it out using `System.out.println()`. Instead loop over the array and print each value.

```
for (String boyName : boyNames) {
    System.out.println(boyName);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boyNames));
```

Another alternative would be to use [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) (new for Java 8)

```
System.out.println(String.join("\n", boyNames));
```

Comment: Erm  there are simpler ways.

Comment: [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) perhaps?

Comment: Thank you!!!! This made it work!

Comment: `Arrays.toString(array)` is even simpler

Comment: Added that one.

Comment: But this is all explained *ad nauseum* in the linked Q&A